# Autoflowing text

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently working on a custom user control to help display a brief rundown of an incident report (using Bootstrap3). The control displays as follows:

[image: Incident Display control]

I need the text to flow around the image to the right. I've tried a few variations on 'pull-left' and 'pull-right', but nothing has quite worked the way I want it to (I'm not super-fantastic with html/css). Here's the code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDept" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <small>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTask" runat="server" />
            </small>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox">
            <asp:Image ID="imgIncident" runat="server" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the lblDesc content to flow around the thumbnail image? The div with a class of col-md-12 will make it sit under the other two divs as it's 12 columns wide

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like to do with lblDesc. We're down an employee today, so the OP was a bit more rushed than I usually prefer.

As for the column layout, that's just the code as it is now. I do know the col-md-12 class basically ensures a new 'line'. I've tried a few variants on where the controls lay, but can't quite get it all to mesh together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the text to auto-flow with the following:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h3 class="col-md-8 pull-left">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDept" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <small>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTask" runat="server" />
        </small>
    </h3>
    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox">
            <asp:Image ID="imgIncident" runat="server" />
        </a>
    </div>        
    <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" />
</div>
```